# Обращение к дочерним элементам JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Нужно обратиться к дочернему элементу чтобы взять его атрибут
Пусть будет такая ситуация:

```
<div class="elements">
    <div class="elem">
        <img scr="1.png"
        <p>Привет стэк</p>
    </div>
    <div class="elem">
        <img scr="1.png"
        <p>Привет стэк</p>
    </div>   
</div>


elem.forEach(element => {
   
})
```

Так вот, я перебираю элементы, и мне нужно достать от туда дочерний элемент  чтобы взять с него атрибут src, как мне это сделать внутри скрипта с перебором?

Comment: Про какой именно элемент речь?

Comment: Мне нужно забрать img из "elem"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно делать ровно так же, как это делается от `document`, т.е. спокойно можно применять `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll`/`getElementById` и прочие методы, только элементом "точкой отсчёта" будет не `document`, а `elem`

Comment: Спасибо, я даже не знал что так можно) Всё получилось)
Скоро приму ответ)